# How to override sklearn classifier's fit() function only?

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn

I would like to use SGDClassifier() in sklearn's library with gridsearchCV to classify something whether it is 1 or 0 with scoring='precision'.  When I split my data using kfold 5 I sometimes run into a situation where some of my y_train splits would only have all 0s or all 1s.  SGDClassifer would spit out an error saying all my labels only have 1 class.  My gridsearchCV() just completely stops.  How do properly handle this case?  I want SGDClassifer to return a precision of 0 and continue the gridsearch.  I tried to write an SGDClassifer2() class which inherits SGDClassifer but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.  Here is my attempt at overriding SGDClassifer's fit:

```
class SGD2(SGDClassifier):

    #
    # only override the fit() function here
    #
    def fit(self, X, y):
        # if array y are all 0s or all 1s
        if((sum(y) == 0) || sum(y) == len(y)):
           return 0
        else:
           return self.fit(X,y)
```

Sorry I am a beginner, any advice or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this looks good  just take care that the proper operator in Python is the word `or`, not the `||` symbol used in languages that inherit the syntax from C.